# Missing feature Apex Classes Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes

Tags: force.com

This error is coming when i am creating the package installer of apex in salesfoce envionment online .Now what i have to do to fix this bug. and can start work on apex. please reply as much as fast as possible.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to install a package into a professional edition org.

This will only work with managed packages that have been appropriately certified by Salesforce.

If using apex is important to you and you need to it quickly the best option is to upgrade your Salesforce edition from Professional or Group Edition to Enterprise Edition or higher.

---

Re:

> I have registered as trial account for 30 days.

From [Package install fail: missing feature apex class](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/AppExchange-Directory-Packaging/Package-install-fail-missing-feature-apex-class/td-p/113576/page/2)
Andrew Smith
Director of Product Management, Force.com

> The 30 day trials do not support Apex code.  If you purchase Enterprise Edition, you can then install this app.  If you want to try it out beforehand, sign up for a developer edition org at developer.force.com.  Then install the app into that org.  That will allow you to try it out before purchase.

So as per Thomas's and Andrew's suggestion. A developer edition org will allow you to try out packages that rely on Apex. You can [Sign up for your FREE Developer environment](https://events.developerforce.com/signup?d=70130000000EjHb).

Comment: Let me inform you that i have registered as trial account for 30 days. so i dont know which edition they have provided me. Is there any way to see the edition in salesforce.

Comment: If you mouse over the title bar/tab name, the full edition name will be in the page title. If you want an Apex development/testing environment for free without a time limit, sign up for a Developer Edition org at http://developer.force.com/